# javascript html into variable with if statements

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am getting values from array and I am using those values in html block and storing that black into variable but I am getting an error "unexpected token if"

My code look like this.

```
@: marker.contentString = '<div class="content" style="width:400px;height:400px;">' +
@:  '<h3><b>'+ markerpoints[i].coursename +'</b></h3>' +
@:  '<p>'+ markerpoints[i].country  +'</p>'+
@:  '<table id="map_table" style="margin-top:5px;" width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5">'+
@:  '<thead style="text-align:left"><tr><th>Date</th><th>Course</th></tr></thead>'+
@:  '<tbody>'+
@:  if(markerpoints[i].ProductName0 != 'undefined'){
@:  '<tr>'+
@:  '<td width="158">'+ markerpoints[i].Fromdate0 +' - '+ markerpoints[i].Todate0 +'</td>'+
@:  '<td><a href="Default.aspx?ID=771&ProductID='+ markerpoints[i].ProductID0 +'">'+ markerpoints[i].ProductName0 +'</a></td>'+
@:  '</tr>'+
@:          }
@:  if(markerpoints[i].ProductName1 !== 'undefined'){
@:  '<tr>'+
@:  '<td width="158">'+ markerpoints[i].Fromdate1 +' - '+ markerpoints[i].Todate1 +'</td>'+
@:  '<td><a href="Default.aspx?ID=771&ProductID='+ markerpoints[i].ProductID1 +'">'+ markerpoints[i].ProductName1 +'</a></td>'+
@:  '</tr>'+
@:      }
@:  if(markerpoints[i].ProductName2 !== 'undefined'){
@:  '<tr>'+
@: '<td width="158">'+ markerpoints[i].Fromdate2 +' - '+ markerpoints[i].Todate2 +'</td>'+
@:  '<td><a href="Default.aspx?ID=771&ProductID='+ markerpoints[i].ProductID2 +'">'+ markerpoints[i].ProductName2 +'</a></td>'+
@:  '</tr>'+
@:                                              }
@:  '</tbody>'+
@:  '</table>'+
@:  '</div>'
```

is this a correct way of writing if statement in this scenario if not how i can prevent that is value is undefined it should not out put value as undefined.

Comment: SUGGES : Use an fu Array and call .join on it !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a ";" before the if, then you need to resume the string concatenation with marker.contentString += '<....

```
@: marker.contentString = '<div class="content" style="width:400px;height:400px;">' +
    @:  '<h3><b>'+ markerpoints[i].coursename +'</b></h3>' +
    @:  '<p>'+ markerpoints[i].country  +'</p>'+
    @:  '<table id="map_table" style="margin-top:5px;" width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5">'+
    @:  '<thead style="text-align:left"><tr><th>Date</th><th>Course</th></tr></thead>'+
    @:  '<tbody>';
    @:  if(markerpoints[i].ProductName0 != 'undefined'){
marker.contentString += 'etc....
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```js
 marker.contentString = '<div class="content" style="width:400px;height:400px;">' +
  '<h3><b>'+ markerpoints[i].coursename +'</b></h3>' +
  '<p>'+ markerpoints[i].country  +'</p>'+
  '<table id="map_table" style="margin-top:5px;" width="100%" cellpadding="10" cellspacing="5">'+
  '<thead style="text-align:left"><tr><th>Date</th><th>Course</th></tr></thead>'+
  '<tbody>';
  if(markerpoints[i].ProductName0 != 'undefined'){
  marker.contentString = marker.contentString +'<tr>'+
  '<td width="158">'+ markerpoints[i].Fromdate0 +' - '+ markerpoints[i].Todate0 +'</td>'+
  '<td><a href="Default.aspx?ID=771&ProductID='+ markerpoints[i].ProductID0 +'">'+ markerpoints[i].ProductName0 +'</a></td>'+
  '</tr>';
          }
  if(markerpoints[i].ProductName1 !== 'undefined'){
  marker.contentString = marker.contentString +'<tr>'+
  '<td width="158">'+ markerpoints[i].Fromdate1 +' - '+ markerpoints[i].Todate1 +'</td>'+
  '<td><a href="Default.aspx?ID=771&ProductID='+ markerpoints[i].ProductID1 +'">'+ markerpoints[i].ProductName1 +'</a></td>'+
  '</tr>';
      }
  if(markerpoints[i].ProductName2 !== 'undefined'){
  marker.contentString = marker.contentString +'<tr>'+
 '<td width="158">'+ markerpoints[i].Fromdate2 +' - '+ markerpoints[i].Todate2 +'</td>'+
  '<td><a href="Default.aspx?ID=771&ProductID='+ markerpoints[i].ProductID2 +'">'+ markerpoints[i].ProductName2 +'</a></td>'+
  '</tr>';
}
  marker.contentString = marker.contentString +'</tbody>'+
  '</table>'+
 '</div>';
```